# Reaction between free radicals and water

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals

Free-radical substitution does not occur in aqueous solution as free radicals react with water (from school textbook). What does the reaction between free radicals, say Br, and water produce?

Comment: You might be referring to electrophilic addition like in the video - I am referring to radical substitution. In your first link there is such a reaction but with Cl radicals instead. Was wondering what happens when these radicals react with water.

Comment: You're right. I deleted my unhelpful comments.

Comment: My best guess would be HBr. Br2 + Water disproportions to HBr and hypobromite. That reaction is sped up by light, so it's probably a radical reaction.

Comment: see this:-http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/how-can-bromine-water-be-called-a-solution

Answer (score 3):

Bromine radical reacts with water

$$\ce{Br* + H2O -> HBr + *OH}$$

OH radical reacts with bromine

$$\ce{*OH + Br2 -> BrOH + Br*}$$

to give a new bromine radical, and so on, until the bromine is totally consumed.