Why does triiodide have only single bonds?
The triiodide ion ($I_3^-$) has structure [I-I-I]$^-$, but the resonance structure [I=I-I]$^-\leftrightarrow$ [I-I=I]$^-$ seems more favourable to me. After all, it disperses formal charge and has a higher bond order. Yet, the triiodide ion being linear shows that the first structure is the correct one. Why?
P.S.: A similar question does exist but asks why the formation of triiodide is possible, rather than why it is the way it is.

The conclusion you draw is unfortunately incorrect. The molecule is linear, but double bonds do not negate this. The bond distance of the molecule, however, it's more consistent with a weak(er) single bond. The whole bonding in this molecule is a bit involved to cover in a comment though.

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/60456/4945

It goes the other way: triiodide ion actually has only one covalent bond, delocalized over the two linkages:
$\ce{\overset{-}{I}:}\space\space\space\space\ce{I – I <-> I – I}\space\space\space\space\ce{:\overset{-}{I}}$
The molecular orbital structure that goes along with this is given in various locations, including here.

Wikipedia by Arun Sridharan
The occupied bonding orbital has less overlap between each pair of atoms than a pairwise bond would, but the combined overlap over both linkages makes the three-center bond stronger than a simple pairwise bond would be.
